# How to compile PythonMagick against custom lib path

Tags: libraries, imagemagick, configure

I want to compile latest PythonMagick.
I am able to compile older one compatible with Ubuntu 14.10 libs, but this version is not sufficient.

First step was compile recent imagemagick packages itself and it's now done 
installed to `/opt/imagemagick-6.8/`

So now I want to compile PythonMagick. ./configure see system libs and ends with

```
Requested 'MagickCore >= 6.8.6' but version of MagickCore is 6.7.7
```

so I need to compile it against `/opt/imagemagick-6.8/lib`
I tried various env properties like

```
MAGICKCORE_LIBS=/opt/...  ./configure
```

same with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc.

but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

... and the solution is

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/imagemagick-6.8/lib/pkgconfig ./configure`